# Quick access SQL queries

Tags: sql-server

I find the often I need to use certain queries frequently to build stored procedures. So instead of going into my saved work, opening it and copying segments across to my new window in SQL. Is there a way I can have them sitting in a toolbar where I can just drag and drop for re-use?

They are small pieces of code usually like the below:

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
 DROP TABLE #Temp;
```

Comment: Perhaps you should create views or table functions.

Comment: [Add Transact-SQL Snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492130.aspx)

Comment: I would need to use something like that daily, but obviously something longer to type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can do it by creating Template in SQL SERVER.

Go to the VIEW menu on top of SSMS and select Template Explorer (Alt+Ctrl+t). You will get default templates, Now right click the SQL SERVER TEMPLATES and click new and select folder and make a new folder there and create files there. Inside those files add all your frequently run queries and you can use it by opening it.